# W8 Phone System.Xml.XmlException &

Tags: c#, xml, windows, windows-phone-8, syndication

With this code it shows that there are no errors but when it is run it keeps crashing, Below is the code and then the debug output;

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceModel.Syndication;

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&q=" + "google" + "&output=rss", settings);
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
```

This is the debug output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\System.Xml.debug.resources.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.ni.dll
'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
```

Call Stack info:

> project.DLL!project.App.RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationFailedEventArgs e) Line 90    C#
>       Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigationFailed(System.Uri uri, System.Exception exception)    Unknown
>       Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(System.IAsyncResult result) Unknown
>       Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(System.AsyncCallback userCallback, System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result) Unknown
>       Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad.AnonymousMethod__0(object args)    Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args)    Unknown
>       System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() Unknown
>       System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority)    Unknown
>       System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context)  Unknown
>       System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args)   Unknown
>       System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pParams, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pResult)   Unknown

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is the file you want to read existent?

Comment: @Arpad Yes, [it is](https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=uk&hl=en&q=google&output=rss). I tried it and it seems to work.

Comment: It shows a A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll error when run @LajosArpad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public void FileDownloadComplete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.Result will contain the files byte for byte

```
// your settings
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore;

// create a memory stream for us to use from the bytes of the downloaded file
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result ?? ""));

// create your reader from the stream of bytes
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms, settings);

// do whatever you want with the reader
// ........

// close
reader.Close()
```